# Modify a Shiny reactive expression with two forms of user input

Tags: shiny, expression, reactive

I want to use a reactive expression that can be updated in either of two ways. Below is a very simple example with either numeric input or a reset button to set the expression back to its original state (in practice the expression is more complex, so can't use reactive values). It seems that only the second definition of num is recognised, so in the example the numeric input is ignored).
What am I missing?
Many thanks!

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("number", "Input", 1),
  actionButton("button", "Reset"),
  textOutput("check")
)
server <- function(input, output){
  num <- reactive({
    input$number
  })
  num <- eventReactive(input$button, {
    1
  })
  output$check <- renderText({
    num()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

We can use `observeEvent()` with each input to update `num()`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("number", "Input", 1),
  actionButton("button", "Reset"),
  textOutput("check")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  num <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$number, {
    num(input$number)
  })

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    num(1)
  })

  observeEvent(c(input$button, input$number), {
    output$check <- renderText({
      num()
    })
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you @jpdugo17, but that getting me where I want. The reactive expression remains responsive only to the reset button, not the numeric input (as you can see by the fact that the output under the reset button doesn't respond to the the numeric input). Any further thoughts? Apologies if my earlier question wasn't clear.

Comment: Should read "...that's *not* getting me where I want..."  To clarify, my problem is getting the expression to respond to both inputs, not updating the numeric input.

Comment: I edited the answer, please take a look.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, you want that the output show the value from `input$number` and if the button is pressed the output should return to 1?

Comment: Well, the output is just my attempt to see what's going on with the reactive expression num (this is just a toy example), but yes, that's essentially it.The problem is that the reactive expression num() only ever responds to the reset button (so taking a value of one ). I want it to respond to the changes in the numeric input as well. You can see from the output that this isn't happening. I suspect that my approach (having two

Comment: @Marcus take a look at the edit, i think we will get this eventually.

Comment: That does the trick! So simple I just couldn't see it. Thank you for your patience @jpdugo17.